# How to change the Oracle Client user in a connection

Tags: oracle, connection, odp.net, tnsnames, tns

I have the oracle 10 and 11 clients instaled in my machine. When i go to the command line and type TNSPING the output tells my something like this

```
TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 16-OUT-2012     09:34:39
```

so, i assume that this machine is using the 10 version of oracle client to handle the connections.

How to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to a command line and type "tnsping" on a Windows machine, whichever Oracle Home is listed first in your PATH environment variable will be the Oracle Home that is used.  If you want the 11g Oracle Home to be the default, you can edit the PATH environment variable (Control Panel | System | Advanced | Environment Variables) and move the 11g Oracle Home path ahead of the 10g Oracle Home path.  Alternately, you should be able to open the Oracle Universal Installer from the 11g install and use the Oracle Home selector that is in that utility to change the order of the paths in your PATH environment variable.  Behind the scenes, that tool is just rearranging the directories in your PATH.

Whether the default Oracle Home is being used by a particular application, though, is a somewhat different matter.  Some applications are set up to use whichever Oracle Home happens to be the default.  Other applications can make use of components installed in the non-default Oracle Home.  Since you tagged this question ODP.Net, I assume that the application(s) you are actually concerned about are using ODP.Net.  If that's the case, you probably want to look through the ODP.Net FAQ where it discusses [using ODP.Net on a client with multiple Oracle Homes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/faq-093106.html#MOH).

Comment: Interresting, what you describes is my first thoughts about this problem. In my case, my ORACLE_HOME envvar is EMPTY and in my PATH envvar i have first the Oracle 11 directory, and in second the Oracle 10 Directory, neverthless the tnsping responses me 10.2.0.1.0. So, i thing i need to fiz the problem that my Oracle_Home envvar is empty. I am reinstaling the oracle clients to try this approach and will post the results later.

Comment: I am testing your answer. Instaled Oracle Client 11, then Oracle Client 10, so the Oracle Client 10 path appears first in the PATH envvar. Rebooted, then a try to rename the Oracle 10 folder, and i was successful, then try to rename oracle client 11 folder and windows told me that some files are in use. So, I thing the order of  Paths in the envvar doesnt mean wich client is used.

Comment: @Ewerton - As I said, the PATH will control which tnsping is used (note that the PATH for a particular `CMD.EXE` window is set when that window is spawned-- changing the Control Panel environment variable will affect future command-line windows, not existing ones).  Other applications may or may not use what is set in the `PATH`-- they may have other ways of controlling which client is used.

Comment: Sorry @Justin Cave, i misunderstood your answer, your above explanation is right. in fact i badly asked the question, my intention was determine what client (10 or 11) one application is using, by my tests, the path variable doenst determine it. I already doesnt find a answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly for the same reason I have made the following tool:
http://oratools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Oracle%20Home%20Selector&referringTitle=Home

it searches for oracle clients installed on machine, and allows to switch current oracle home by modifying registry, environment variables and registered libraries

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.